# Inserting into table from another table with an extra variable

Tags: sql

I have two tables

```
Table A 
(
unique id, -- sum of the records
Data1,
Data2
)

Table B
(
Data1,
Data2
)
```

I need to insert from table B into table A and add the records in.  I had a simple insert like this:

```
Insert into A select * from B
```

but that does not work due to the unique ID.

I tried something like:

```
INSERT INTO A
SELECT 1+SELECT MAX(UniqueID) FROM A,temp.* 
FROM B temp;
```

But this does not work.  Can anyone think of a way I can get the first parameter to be a count of the records, obviously it would need to increase by one each time a new record is added.

Comment: what error has been generated?

Comment: is id an auto-increment id? is so then you don't need to set it. Then just do `Insert into A select data1, data2 from B`

Comment: The error is unknown table and it highlights temp.*.   However, if I separately do a select * from temp then it works so the table seems fine.

Comment: The original table is already created, not sure I would be allowed to update it to be auto-increment, although it probably should have been that to begin with

Comment: I have to say I think this is a bad idea. If you have multiple sessions coming in, they're going to interact in strange ways.

Comment: I appreciate your attempt to help but I pretty much have to do this. The table exists as it is and the updates we get do not have our key field in them. Only one of these updates will be run at the same time so clashes would be highly unlikely. Once again, I appreciate your attempt to help and am keen to hear any ideas you have

Comment: Okay I have solved it.  I gave up using SQL and wrapped it in a C++ exe.  Thanks to all who tried to help!

Answer (score 1):

Just set `id` to be an auto-increment column in the table declaration:

```
create table A (
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  Data1 <sometype>,
  Data2 <sometype>
);
```

Then you can insert rows from `B`:

```
insert into A (Data1, Data2) 
select Data1, Data2 from B
```

Each new row in `A` will get a new, unique auto-increment value for `id`.

---

Note: not experienced with plsql, but this is what I'd do with MySQL.

Comment: The original table is already created, not sure I would be allowed to update it to be auto-increment, although it probably should have been that to begin with.  Is there another way?

Comment: @SteveTaylor -- in that case, @@Hadmacker's answer might be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In past Oracle DB's, I've used a sequence to create a primary key ID for Table A, so you should be able to do this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE A_SEQ
MINVALUE 1
MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 20;    

insert into A (id, Data1, Data2)  select A_SEQ.nextval, Data1, Data2 from B
```

See this url for details: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php

** In SQL Server, you can use the "autoincrement" attribute on a column to do the same.
** SQL Server 2012 will also be gaining a similar Sequence mechanism, though its syntax is quite different than this.

** Edit: My preference is still to use sequences, but as an alternative, this re-work of your original SELECT statement might be helpful:

```
INSERT INTO A (UniqueID, Data1, Data2) 
SELECT 
    (SELECT MAX(UniqueID) + 1 FROM A)
  , Data1
  , Data2 
FROM B
```

Comment: This looks pretty good - is there a way I can set the minvalue to be the current row total?  I tried MINVALUE MAX(uniqueID) FROM A but it complains that it is an invalid number.  I had a look on the link but they did not seem to cover it.

Comment: Unfortunately you won't be able to use min/max that way with sequences. When you call nextval, you are receiving a unique number that is always the next one in the sequence and will never be called again. (trans rollbacks, etc, will cause an ID to skip) If you need to always have a sequential ID, You might want to look at a "BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER" so you do your insert normally without the ID, and before inserting, the trigger will do the SELECT MAX(ID)... bit for you. You can seen an example here, though they still use it with a sequence: http://www.datanamic.com/support/autoinc-oracle.html

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use a triggger (house rules).  This is driving me mad as I know it is easy but I cannot quite nail it down!